# Command line conda with 2 anaconda installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

To make easier migration, 2 Anaconda versions have been installed on Windows:
Anaconda 27  and Anaconda 34

However, on the command line `conda update ....`,
how can I specify the right 'conda.exe' 
apart from putting the full path for `conda`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Recommended Solution - Using `conda` Environments

Instead of installing two different Anaconda version, I would recommend
to use `conda` environments.  Create one for Python 2.7:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
```

Now, you can activate it with:

```
activate py27
```

the prompt will change to

```
(py27)
```

and:

```
(py27) conda install anaconda
```

will install all Anaconda packages.

Likewise, do it for Python 3.5:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5  anaconda
```

This will install all anaconda packages right away.

## Solutions for Already Installed Multiple Anaconda Versions

If you already have installed two Anaconda versions these solutions might work for you.

### Using two command line windows

You can set the `PATH` environmental variable.

In your first shell do:

```
set PATH=C:\path\to\conda2;$PATH$
```

and in your second:

```
set PATH=C:\path\to\conda3;$PATH$
```

Now `conda` should be the version you set with the `PATH`.

### Using one command line window

You can a create two batch files that you put in your `PATH`:

`conda2.cmd`

```
C:\path\to\conda2\conda.exe
```

`conda3.cmd`

```
C:\path\to\conda3\conda.exe
```

Now `conda2` should start the Python 2 and `conda3` the Python 3 version.

Comment: Added a solution to my answer.

Comment: ok, which anaconda should I install first ? (2.7 or 3.6)

And, how to install the other python interpreter ?

Comment: I highly recommend to go with `conda` environments. They are made for your use case. No need to re-invent the wheel.